# Kong apigateway with Grpc

Tags: java, grpc-java, kong

how to configure Grpc with kong Apigateway? (mean all the services are written in Grpc and how to use kong API gateway for routing.
I tried following this( https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/kong-plugins/configuring-a-grpc-service/)
but the first step is only not working all the requests are working fine. I installed kong in ubuntu.

Comment: Could you post the error messages you got and how to replicate it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.